# How to enable only few protocols in TLSv1.2

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I'm using TLSv1.2 along with OpenSSL version 1.1.1g and Apache version 2.4.35 in my Java application. Here I want to enable only 3 protocols(chacha20-poly1305, AES-GCM, AES-CCM), and I want to block the remaining protocols in TLSv1.2.

I added those 3 protocols in **SSLCipherSuite** which was present in the **ssl.conf** file.

```
SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

But it is not working. Please find the below error details,

> SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.2'

Kindly let me know the changes which I need to make only those 3 protocols work.

Comment: *"it is not working"*  is no useful error description. How did you check, what did you expect to happen, what happened instead?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich..Please have a look at the edited post.

Comment: The error message suggests that your server does not support TLSv1.2, which conflicts with what you have written regading OpenSSL version. Are you sure that the Apache you are using is actually compiled with the OpenSSL version?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich..Thank you for your reply. Yes, I'm sure that the apache is compiled with the OpenSSL version. After this error, I thought of adding the TLSv1.3 protocol because TLSv1.3 has stronger security. But my apache version doesn't support that. Whether there is any way to add TLSv1.3 with apache 2.4.35?

Comment: Not supporting TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 sounds very much like being compiled with an old OpenSSL version. What system you are running? Do the versions of Apache and OpenSSL you want to use come with the system or do you have added these later?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich..  The Java application is running on RHEL 8.4 OS. I have downloaded apache from the official website and configured it as per my requirement. Please have a look at the below link, which describes TLS 1.3 is not supported by Apache 2.4.35. 

[link]https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/www-announce/201809.mbox/%3C3b0ea0e5-9940-f238-4a1b-f395ce67abb4@apache.org%3E

Comment: The java application is irrelevant since the access is done through Apache. The version of apache you've download explicitly does not support OpenSSL 1.1.1, yet you claim that you are using it. This does not match. So it is unclear how your stack really looks like.  Moreover the latest Apache which comes with RHEL 8 is 2.4.37, so why not use this directly from the RH instead installing something external?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich.. I'm using external Apache because I have customized it as per my requirement. The customization is not possible with RHEL Apache. And I'm sure that OpenSSL 1.1.1 works fine with external Apache 2.4.35. Please let me know whether Apache 2.4.35 supports TLSv1.3 or not.

Comment: You've already cited the release information which clearly state that TLS 1.3 is not supported.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich.. Do you think whether I need to modify the above details(SSLCipherSuite) to make only those 3 protocols from TLS 1.2 work?

Comment: The error message clearly says that TLS 1.2 is not supported by the server. So I doubt that the server is compiled against OpenSSL 1.1.1. Doing anything which the ciphers will not change this problem.